# How to start a different animation for each object JavaFX

Tags: animation, javafx

I built a project thats creats a grid 6X6 elements of type `Block`. When I click on a `Block`, a orange circle appears. The problem is that I want a button that when I click on it, it makes each circle, that is visible, move right, left, up, or down randomly every second. Like one circle goes up, then it goes left, then it goes again up, ect.

```
class Block extends StackPane {

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(40, 40);

    Circle circ = new Circle(20);
    EventHandler a = new EventHandler() {
        public void handle(Event t) {
            circ.setVisible(true);
        }
    };

    Block() {

        rect.setFill(Paint.valueOf("WHITE"));
        rect.setStroke(Paint.valueOf("BLACK"));
        rect.setOnMouseClicked(a);
        circ.setFill(Paint.valueOf("ORANGE"));
        circ.setVisible(false);

        this.getChildren().addAll(rect, circ);
    }

}
```

```
public class JavaFXApplication8 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        Block[][] matrice = new Block[6][6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            matrice[i] = new Block[6];
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                matrice[i][j] = new Block();
                root.add(matrice[i][j], j, i);
            }
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question: Use `Color.ORANGE` instead of `Paint.valueOf("ORANGE")` (`Color extends Paint`).

Comment: have a look at http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/06/14/using-the-javafx-animationtimer/

Answer (score 0):

I made an example with javaFX [AnimationTimer](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) to show how you can use it,in this example the `AnimationTimer` makes a random circle of your Blocks visible or unvisible(randomly).

*Add this into the start method of your app after (`primaryStage.show();` for example)*:

```
// AnimationTimer
    new AnimationTimer() {

        Random random = new Random();
        private long nextSecond = 0;
        private long refreshRate = 1_000_000_000L / 6;

        @Override
        public void handle(long startNanos) {

             //refreshing every 1 second/6
             //(if you don't set that then it will try to run
             // as fast as 50 frames per second)
            if (startNanos > nextSecond) { 
                nextSecond = startNanos + refreshRate;

                // Choose some random Numbers
                int randomColumn = random.nextInt(6);
                int randomRow = random.nextInt(6);
                System.out.println(randomColumn + "," + randomRow);

                // Do a random item visible
                matrice[randomColumn][randomRow].circ.setVisible(random.nextBoolean());                             

            }
        }
    }.start();
```

*To move the blocks on the `GridPane` you can use the method:

```
     GridPane.setConstraints(Node node,int column,int row);
```

and other http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html